# perform operation on selected columns of dataframe based on threshold present in another dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([["A",1,98,56,61,1,4,6], ["B",1,79,54,36,2,5,7], ["C",1,97,32,83,3,6,8],["B",1,96,31,90,4,7,9], ["C",1,45,32,12,5,8,10], ["A",1,67,33,55,6,9,11]], columns=["id","date","c1","c2","c3","x","y","z"])
```

I have another dataframe where conditions for selected columns are present

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([["c2",40], ["c1",80], ["C3",90]], columns=["col","condition"])
```

Perform operations on df1 based on conditions present in df2. Like if the value for c1 is 80 in df2, change the values present in column c1 of df1 to -1 if the value is less than 80, if higher than 80 then change values to 1. Perform similar operations for other columns which are present in df2 also.

**Expected Output:**

```
df_out = pd.DataFrame([["A",1,1,1,-1,1,4,6], ["B",1,-1,1,-1,2,5,7], ["C",1,1,-1,-1,3,6,8],["B",1,1,-1,1,4,7,9], ["C",1,-1,-1,-1,5,8,10], ["A",1,-1,-1,-1,6,9,11]], columns=["id","date","c1","c2","c3","x","y","z"])
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert `df2` to `Series` first, then create mask for compare with columns names, compre for greater or equal by [`DataFrame.ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ge.html) by `Series` and pass to [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
s = df2.set_index('col')['condition']

m = df1.columns.isin(s.index)
df1.loc[:, m] = np.where(df1.loc[:, m].ge(s), 1, -1)
print (df1)
  id  date  c1  c2  c3  x  y   z
0  A     1   1   1  -1  1  4   6
1  B     1  -1   1  -1  2  5   7
2  C     1   1  -1  -1  3  6   8
3  B     1   1  -1   1  4  7   9
4  C     1  -1  -1  -1  5  8  10
5  A     1  -1  -1  -1  6  9  11
```